# how do i take something out of list of dict and gather it into another dict with no dictionary name

Tags: python, list, dictionary

here's part of sample in caption_file

```
[{'text': 'okay Wow', 'start': 0.03, 'duration': 6.499}, {'text': '[Music]', 'start': 8.3, 'duration': 5.919}]
```

i have a bunch of samples in CAPTIONS_DIR and i want to gather some item into another dictionary

```
import os

from .step import Step
from yt_concate.setting import CAPTIONS_DIR

class ReadCaption(Step):
def process(self, data, inputs, utils):
    for caption_file in os.listdir(CAPTIONS_DIR):
        with open(os.path.join(CAPTIONS_DIR, caption_file), "r") as f:
            captions = {}
            for line in f:
                caption = line["text"]
                time = str(line["start"]) + "-->" + str(line["start"])
                captions[caption] = time
            print(captions)
```

the result and where i've been trapped

```
caption = line["text"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

but if i enter a integer 0 it'll come up "["

```
for line in f:
    print(line[0])
```

Comment: You're just reading the file **as text**. If you want to turn it into an actual list of dicts, try `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Your file looks like it's in json format, what about trying to parse the content in json?

Comment: @maya That's not JSON.

Comment: `with open(..) as f: data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())` `for line in data: print(line['text'])`… Assuming that "part of the caption file" is representative and it contains exactly one list.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for helping. I'll chewing on it

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this -

```
print(line[0]['text'])
```

Comment: yeah i have tried and the same error

Comment: If `line["text"]` already says `string indices must be integers`, that means **`line` is a string**. Using even more list offsets on it won't help.

Comment: @deceze  i see. but after i search on the internet, i found the only way to grab index from string is to use integer in line

Comment: @kinslersi See my comment under your question and the duplicate linked on top of your question. This here is a dead end.

Comment: @deceze Thank you for your time! But sorry I still not get it. I tried ast.literal_eval(), json.loads(), etc and went wrong in the end. In the other hand, I was wondering the reason after I convert it and it'll eventually come up the same list of dict.

Comment: @deceze  I'm kind of mess up now and the result underneath TypeError: string indices must be integers            
                    #  for line in f:
                    data = dict(ChainMap(*line))